# how to add item number xslt in to <xsl:for-each>

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

firts... My English is very bad Sorry :( 
Well, I am trying to export an xml with xslt, after much searching, getting it "+ - ",  this is my first working with xslt, the problem is CREATE item number '' not get it, please help me.

Thank
my xslt

```
               <xsl:for-each select="fm:COL[50]/fm:DATA">
                    <det>
                        <xprod>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </xprod>
                    </det>
               </xsl:for-each>
```

My Result

```
<det>
   <xprod>CALCAS MASCULINA CORTADAS</xprod>
</det>
<det> 
  <xprod>CALCAS MASCULINA </xprod>
</det>
```

I need

```
<det nItem "1">
 <xprod>CALCAS MASCULINA CORTADAS</xprod>
</det>
<det nItem "2">
 <xprod>CALCAS MASCULINAS</xprod>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="fm:COL[50]/fm:DATA">
                <det nItem="{position()}" >
                    <xprod>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </xprod>
                </det>
           </xsl:for-each>
```

---

Untested, because no code to allow testing was provided.