# how to export relations table -filemaker xml xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, filemaker

my question is, how to export related fields in xml filemaker
Ex: table A is
id
name
city

Table B
id
city

table A and B related with id

need result:

```
<cities>
   <name>MIKE</name>
      <city>Barcelona</city>
      <city>Madrid</city>
   <name>PETER</name>
      <city>Barcelona</city>
      <city>Barcelona</city>
      <city>Barcelona</city>
</cities>
```

Comment: Not sure where exactly you are stuck with this. Export from the parent table and include the `city` field from the child table in the export field order. Then create a `city` element for each `DATA` in the `ROW` that corresponds to `city` - just like in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62481280/how-to-add-item-number-xslt-in-to-xslfor-each). -- Note that the indentation of the result in your question is misleading: all elements except the root `cities` are siblings.

Comment: thank you for your patience

Comment: thank you for your patience is my firts xslt , learning a lot, and other problem is  i, don't know  define correctily the                         <code><xsl:value-of select="."/></code> ( is related, is ok )
<product><xsl:value-of select="."/></product> .. ( is related :( same result )  I use "." and... not is correct, where is the correct format ?